# Store Magento media files on Google cloud

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, google-api, google-cloud

I need to store my media files on google cloud whenever i add products image or other media files. I am trying to use https://github.com/bangerkuwranger/magento2-google-cloud-storage module and i need below credentials. But as i never used google cloud storage i don't know how to get them. Can any one provide me guideline to do that.

[image]

Or you can suggest me any other **module** or other **process** to upload image and get those from frontend that.